# No se muestran los íconos de calendario y reloj en el admin de Django

Tags: python, django

Tengo este pequeño incoveniente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los iconos que deberían aparecer en la parte de calendario y reloj no se están mostrando. He estado buscando la solución y encontré soluciones que al parecer ya estan deprecadas, por ejemplo que añadiera en settings:

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

Sin embargo esto no me funciona.

Mi archivo settings.py:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'invoiceapp',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'invoice.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'invoice.wsgi.application'


# Database

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Supongo que esto debe ser bastante común, ¿alguien sabe como arreglarlo?

Comment: ¿Estas usando `DEBUG = True`?

Comment: Si, estoy usando `DEBUG = True`

Comment: Estas usando el servidor de pruebas de Django? o ya estas en producción?

Comment: Servidor de pruebas.

Answer (score 3):

Por tu imagen puedo deducir que estás usando Django 1.9, no deberías tener que definir `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` en tu `settings.py`.

[`ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.4/#django-contrib-admin) ha sido deprecado desde la versión 1.4, solo necesitas usar [`STATIC_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#static-url). Intenta lo siguiente, elimina o comenta esa línea:

```
# ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

En tu archivo `urls.py`, agrega esto al final:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    # Tus urls
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Reinicia e intenta de nuevo. La función `static` es la que te ayuda a [servir los archivos](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) cuando te encuentras en modo "debug" (`DEBUG = True`), es decir, cuando estás en la etapa de desarrollo.

Esto evita que tengas que darte el trabajo de implementar un Web server (Apache, Nginx) para servir tus archivos.

Comment: En mis settings no tengo definidas MEDIA_URL y MEDIA_ROOT. No se supone que MEDIA_ROOT es la dirección para los archivos subidos por los usuarios, y pues si no he hecho nada de esto por el momento no lo necesito?

Comment: @JavierCárdenas es posible que tengas razón en eso, ¿puedes mostrar tu `settings.py`? En tu imagen sale `missing-admin-media-prefix` y no veo esa ruta por ningún lado. Pega el código que realmente estás usando

Comment: @JavierCárdenas he actualizado mi respuesta, sin embargo he tratado de replicar tu caso y no me pasa lo mismo. A mi me muestra los widgets del calendario sin problemas

Comment: Probé re-instalando django y probando con otros navegadores. Me funcionó bien con IE y Firefox, no se porque Chrome no los muestra.